# Выровнять блок по центру контейнера

Tags: html, css

Товарищи подскажите, как выровнять блок меню по центру который большей ширины контейнера в котором он лежит... ? )[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: разметка и стили где ? вам не нужно решение ?

Comment: спасибо, уже решил

Comment: вопрос удалите ..но решили ни верно

Comment: почем не верно ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так, для любой ширины.

```css
.little{
  width: 200px;
  padding: 50px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
}

.big{
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="little">
  <div class="big"></div>
<div>
```

Comment: спасибо, бро ) с минусовым margin это не верно

Comment: @Евген где там отрицательный margin ?

Answer (score 0):

Понял решение , задать margin-left: -20px;, может быть и не 20px , эта ширина берется из половины выступающей части